# Is there a way to list all members of a discord server with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to retrieve a list with all people which are part of the discord server.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = 'my_token'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@bot.command()
async def members(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        await ctx.send(member)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Whenever using !members I just get a List of all members which are currently in a voice channel or in some way active on the server where but I'd like to get those  just shown as online or even offline.
Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last updates you have to enable intents. Enable them from the dev portal and code it self.

[image]

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)
```

Remove that line with `server = bot.get_guild(SERVER_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

[Guild.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Guild.members) will return a list of members in the guild.

Since >=1.5.0 requires elevated intents for Member/Presence events, you must enable the Member intents in the developer portal and in your code.

You're also checking for the number of members in which the command is invoked, so you would want to use the [`guild_only()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=guild_only#discord.ext.commands.guild_only) decorator and remove the line with `bot.get_guild()`

Reason for having the `guild_only()` decorator is because if you invoke `!members` in a DM, guild would be None and will raise an error saying that `'NoneType' object has no attribute called 'members'`